# Why do we consider an infinite semicircular contour for the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, intuition, residue-calculus

I have noticed that $\begin{align*}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx \end{align*}$ can be solved using residue theorem.

My question is that while the actual integral doesn't have a closed path, it's a line integral that goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, so while using residue theorem and after replacing $x$ by $z$ why do we consider a semi-circular contour over positive imaginary plane.

How does an open line integral change into a closed loop integral? It would be better if someone can explain it intuitively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the integral exists,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
= \lim_{r \to \infty} \int_{-r}^r
= \lim_{r \to \infty} \left( \oint_{\text{boundary of semicircle}} - \int_{\text{semicircular arc}} \right) $$

A typical proof method using this fact is:

- Compute $\oint_{\text{boundary of semicircle}}$ by the residue theorem
- Show that $\int_{\text{semicircular arc}}$ converges to zero. This is often done by showing the magnitude of the integrand is asymptotically smaller than the arclength

Comment: +1, Nice answer. Unfortunately, I still don't understand how the integration around the semi-circular arc converges to $0$, could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @paulplusx: It doesn't, in general. When applying this technique to solve a particular problem, proving it converges to zero is one of the tasks you need to do.

Comment: Ohh, understood. So it essentially means that whenever such questions are solved with residue method, the semi-circular arc integral converges to $0$. That's the intuition I required, thank you.

Comment: I searched a bit on this and found something called [Jordan's Lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma). I think it shows the proof for the above arc integral to vanish.